# Ending Array after it has finished

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am making a quiz application with a lot of questions. The error i run into is whenever i complete all the quiz questions i get this: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:`
I know my array is out of bounds but now how do i end it after it has completed all items in the array?

My code is as follows:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vehicle);

    mScoreView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
    mQuestionView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
    mButtonChoice1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice1);
    mButtonChoice2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice2);
    mButtonChoice3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice3);
    mImageView=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    updateQuestion();


    //Start of Button Listener for Button1
    mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            //My logic for Button goes in here
            counter = counter +1;
            mImageView.setImageResource(imageID[counter]);
            if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer){
                mScore = mScore + 1;
                updateScore(mScore);
                updateQuestion();

                //This line of code is optiona
                Toast.makeText(VehicleActivity.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }else {
                Toast.makeText(VehicleActivity.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateQuestion();
            }
        }
    });

    //End of Button Listener for Button1

    //Start of Button Listener for Button2
    mButtonChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            //My logic for Button goes in here
            counter = counter +1;
            mImageView.setImageResource(imageID[counter]);
            if (mButtonChoice2.getText() == mAnswer){
                mScore = mScore + 1;
                updateScore(mScore);
                updateQuestion();
                //This line of code is optiona
                Toast.makeText(VehicleActivity.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(VehicleActivity.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateQuestion();
            }
        }
    });

    //End of Button Listener for Button2


    //Start of Button Listener for Button3
    mButtonChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            //My logic for Button goes in here
            counter = counter +1;
            mImageView.setImageResource(imageID[counter]);

            if (mButtonChoice3.getText() == mAnswer){
                mScore = mScore + 1;
                updateScore(mScore);
                updateQuestion();
                //This line of code is optiona
                Toast.makeText(VehicleActivity.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(VehicleActivity.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateQuestion();
            }
        }
    });

    //End of Button Listener for Button3





}

private void updateQuestion(){

    mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
    mButtonChoice1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(mQuestionNumber));
    mButtonChoice2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(mQuestionNumber));
    mButtonChoice3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(mQuestionNumber));

    mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
    mQuestionNumber++;
}


private void updateScore(int point) {
    mScoreView.setText("" + mScore);
}
```

I am using another java file to store all my questions, choices and correct answers called

```
mQuestionLibrary
```

So all i would like to know is how to end this array loop and show the user their total score.

Comment: You have a arraylist or array?

Comment: @GursheeshSingh i have an array `private String mQuestions [] = {};`

Comment: `if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer){` this is not how to compare Strings in Java

Comment: mQuestions.length() will give you the size of the array

Comment: simply add throws exception in method or check MQUESTIONNUMBER < mQuestions.length()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put an if statement in the `updateQuestion()` function that checks the `myQuestionNumber` var to see if it has exceeded the number of questions that are supposed to be answered, and when it does, redirect execution somewhere where it clears the buttons and progresses to the next stage.

Something like

```
if (myQuestionNumber >= MAX_QUESTION_NUM) {
    clearButtons();
    showResults();
} else {
    myQuestionNumber++;
}
```

Also, you shouldn't need to use both a `counter` variable and a `myQuestionNumber` variable. They serve the same purpose, and store the same (or off-by-one) value. Just use myQuestionNumber when referencing the array.

Comment: should this be `if (myQuestionNumber >= MAX_QUESTION_NUM) {`